# How to distribute elements of an array to other arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Here's an array:

`$points = @(9,4,8,9,3,8,5,3,6,10,8,5,2,1,7,7,5,3,6,10)`

There are 20 numbers here and it sums up to 119. I need to distribute this to `GroupA` and `GroupB` equally. So with simple math, GroupA should have 10 points totaling either 59 or 60. Same goes for GroupB. Need to also scale this array out if needed.

Here's what I have so far but I'm pretty sure is NOT the right way (perhaps a terrible way) of doing it. How do I do this? Please help.

```
function DistributePoints()
{
    $points = @(9,4,8,9,3,8,5,3,6,10,8,5,2,1,7,7,5,3,6,10)
    $randomPoints = $points | Sort {Get-Random}

    $groupA = @()
    $groupB = @()


    $perGroupPoints = ($randomPoints | measure -Sum).Sum / 2
    $perGroupPointsMax = [math]::Ceiling(($randomPoints | measure -Sum).Sum / 2)
    $perGroupPointsMin = [math]::Floor(($randomPoints | measure -Sum).Sum / 2)

    for ($i=0; $i -le $randomPoints.Count; $i++)
    {
        $groupACount = ($groupA | measure -Sum).Sum
        if ($groupACount -le $perGroupPoints)
        {
            $groupA += $randomPoints[$i]
            $groupB = $randomPoints[($i+1)..($randomPoints.Count-1)]
        }
    }

    $result = @{
        groupA = $groupA
        groupB = $groupB
    }

    return $result
}

do {
    $run = DistributePoints
    $sum = ($run.groupA | measure -Sum).Sum
    $count = $run.groupA.Count
} until (($sum -eq $perGroupPointsMin -or $sum -eq $perGroupPointsMax) -and ($count -ge ($randomPoints.Count/2)))


$groupA = $run.groupA
$groupB = $run.groupB


# Write the output

Write-Host "---------- Team A ----------"
Write-Host "Sum = $(($groupA | measure -Sum).Sum)"
Write-Host "Players = "(($groupA | sort) -join ",")
Write-Host "Count = $($groupA.Count)"
Write-Host "---------- Team B ----------"
Write-Host "Sum = $(($groupB | measure -Sum).Sum)"
Write-Host "Count = $($groupB.Count)"
Write-Host "Players = "(($groupB | sort) -join ",")
```

Result:

```
---------- Team A ----------
Sum = 60
Players =  1,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9
Count = 10


---------- Team B ----------
Sum = 59
Count = 10
Players =  2,3,3,5,5,6,7,8,10,10
```

Comment: What do you expect if you have 19 numbers = 1, and one number = 100?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers : Else condition `Invalid operation since no point of grouping :P`

Comment: Are you saying, you want unique numbers for each team that sums up to the values you are after or just that it never exceeds 60?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, like Ranadip said probably throw some kind of error saying there's would be a big difference in points between the two groups.

Comment: @postanote Yes. 2nd line in the function, I randomize the array so that there's new/shuffled points in the groups every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you have posted, relative to the output, you could do this as well.

```
'A','B' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $GroupID = "group$PSItem"
    $run.$GroupID | 
    Measure-Object -Sum | 
    Select-Object @{
        Name       = 'TeamGroup'
        Expression = {$GroupID}},
    Sum, Count, 
    @{
        Name       = 'Players'
        Expression = {($run.$GroupID | Sort) -join ','}
     }
}

# Results
<#
TeamGroup Sum Count Players              
--------- --- ----- -------              
groupA     61    10 2,3,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,9  
groupB     58    10 1,3,3,4,5,6,8,8,10,10
#>
```

Yet you could simplify all of what you have to just this (if I am understanding your use case correctly):

```
Clear-host
$Points = @(9,4,8,9,3,8,5,3,6,10,8,5,2,1,7,7,5,3,6,10)
'A','B', 'C' | 
ForEach {
    $TeamTotal   = $null
    Do 
    {
        $TeamPoints = $Points     | Get-Random -Count 10 
        $TeamTotal  = $TeamPoints |  Measure-Object -Sum
    }
    Until($TeamTotal.Sum -match '59|60')

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TeamName   = "Team $PSItem"
        PointCount = $TeamTotal.Count
        PointTotal = $TeamTotal.Sum
        Players    = $TeamPoints -join ','
    }
}
# Results
<#
TeamName PointCount PointTotal Players             
-------- ---------- ---------- -------             
Team A           10         60 5,8,1,8,9,7,3,9,6,4 
Team B           10         59 3,10,8,8,2,9,5,5,8,1
Team C           10         60 8,9,8,5,5,1,3,6,8,7
#>
```

***Update based on your comment***

> There's a small bug though. The goal is to evenly distribute points between the x number of teams. Since the points totals to 119 in this case which is an odd number, two teams should have 59 or 60 points each.

```
Function Show-TeamScoreReport
{
    Param
    (
        $TeamNames  = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a teamname, comma seperated. For Example: A,B,C,etc...')  
    )

    $TeamCount = $TeamNames.Split(',').Count
    $Points,
    $RandomCount,
    $PerTeamSkillsMin,
    $PerTeamSkillsMax,
    $TeamTotal,
    $TeamPoints = $null

    [void]([System.Collections.ArrayList]$Points = @(9,4,8,9,3,8,5,3,6,10,8,5,2,1,7,7,5,3,6,10))

    $RandomCount      = [Math]::Round($Points.Count / $TeamCount)

    $PerTeamSkillsMin = [math]::Floor(($Points   | measure -Sum).Sum / $TeamCount)
    $PerTeamSkillsMax = [math]::Ceiling(($Points | measure -Sum).Sum / $TeamCount)

    $TeamNames | 
    ForEach{
        Do
        {
            $TeamTotal = (
                            $TeamPoints = $Points | 
                            Get-Random -Count $RandomCount 
                         ) | 
                         Measure-Object -Sum
        } 
        Until($TeamTotal.Sum -match "$PerTeamSkillsMin|$PerTeamSkillsMax")

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TeamName   = "Team $PSItem"
            PointCount = $TeamTotal.Count
            PointTotal = $TeamTotal.Sum
            Players    = $TeamPoints -join ','
        }

        $TeamPoints  | 
        ForEach-Object {$Points.RemoveAt($Points.IndexOf($PSItem))}
    }
}

Show-TeamScoreReport -TeamNames A
# Results
<#
TeamName PointCount PointTotal Players                                  
-------- ---------- ---------- -------                                  
Team A           20        119 5,6,5,2,8,7,4,8,1,7,9,3,5,9,10,8,6,3,3,10
#>


Show-TeamScoreReport -TeamNames A,B
# Results
<#
TeamName PointCount PointTotal Players             
-------- ---------- ---------- -------             
Team A           10         60 3,9,5,7,10,8,3,8,1,6
Team B           10         59 7,9,3,8,6,2,5,4,10,5
#>


Show-TeamScoreReport -TeamNames A,B,C
# Results
<#
TeamName PointCount PointTotal Players       
-------- ---------- ---------- -------       
Team A            7         40 7,5,10,7,3,3,5
Team B            7         40 10,1,9,8,6,2,4
Team C            6         39 3,8,8,6,5,9   
#>
```

Comment: I like the second answer; I was looking for a simpler solution like that. There's a small bug though. The goal is to evenly distribute points between the x number of teams. Since the points totals to 119 in this case which is an odd number, two teams should have 59 or 60 points each. If you add a third team, it would have to be like 39,40,40.

Since the goal is to only have two teams, don't have to worry about the scenario of having a third team. I ran this with just 'A','B' teams to loop on and sometimes I get 60,60 or 59,59.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries. Be safe out there.